# Does mmap allow creating a mapping that is much larger than the amount of physical memory?

Tags: linux, mmap

Obviously, `mmap` is limited by the size of the largest available block of virtual address space. But let's assume we have a 64-bit system, where this is almost unlimited for most purposes. Let's also assume no swap  partition is configured.

In the case of an anonymous mapping, the size would have to be limited to the total amount of physical memory available.

However, in the case of a file-backed mapping, I wonder if there is a limit based on the amount of physical memory, e.g., the size of the mapping can be at most X times the amount of physical memory? Or will `mmap` allow me to map arbitrarily large files as a single chunk as long as virtual address space limits are not hit? For example, if I have 32 GiB of RAM, can I successfully `mmap` a 1 TiB disk file?

Asking about Linux specifically, in case it matters. (I tried with a 64 GiB file, and it seems to work. Unfortunately I don't have much more disk space available than that.)

Comment: *can I successfully mmap a 1 TiB disk file* - why not?

Comment: For further reading I found this answer very helpful. Note that for mmap the physical RAM is disk cache (AFAIK) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680928/20140

Answer (score 7):

Using `mmap()` to map a file does not copy the file to physical memory so there's no reason to limit it. As long as the entire file can be represented by the virtual address space, it can be mapped. The way this works is that each page is not resident in memory and so accessing it triggers a page fault. The kernel transparently uses this opportunity to access that part of the file. This allows a user process to operate on a very large file without doing a bunch of [inefficient](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/474926/164143) `read()`, `write()`, and `seek()` loops (although it still causes context switches, as *something* has to actually deal with VFS).

Note that anonymous mappings *can* exceed remaining physical memory if [memory overcommit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441364/164143) is enabled since the page table is set so that each of the virtual pages [points to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556482/164143) the physical [zero page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35547665/9782169). Any read will return zeros, but a write will cause a page fault and the kernel will need to find a free physical page to store the data, at which time it can update the page tables. This requires you have enough physical memory+swap, of course. Overcommit is a useful optimization as most memory allocators will aggressively request memory for their heaps, even if most of it goes unused.

You can even map a file [larger than the address space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/726527/9782169), but not all at once with one `mmap()` call.

---

As an addendum, even on a 64-bit system, you may not be able to use a full 64-bit address space:

```
$ grep -m1 "address sizes" /proc/cpuinfo 
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

On that system, because the 48-bit virtual address space is split in two, you could map a file as large as 2<sup>47</sup> bytes or 128 TiB (actually a little less, because *some* address space will already be in use).

Comment: Good point about anonymous mappings. I should have said that if we want to make an anonymous mapping and have all of it be *usable*, then its size would have to be limited by physical memory.

Comment: @BrianBi Usable for writing, at least. You can still read from an anonymous mapping larger than your physical memory because each page points to the zero page, but as soon as you try to write to a page, a fault occurs and the kernel needs to find an actual free physical page to put the data (at which point it also updates the page tables so the virtual page points to the new physical page, not the zero page).